# new local mysql database without root access?

Tags: mysql

MySQL is installed.

Can I set up a new local MySQL database with out root access? Or get anything running without root access? No one around me seems to know the root password to the server that is already running? Though one group is interacting with a MySQL database that I can see but don't yet have access to.

I haven't found the part in the documentation that tells you what to do when 1) you have no root access 2) there is no admin (or none found yet).

I am behind an awful firewall and can only sometimes manage to get local installs to work ... otherwise I would basically go for sqlite3 just to get something up a running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a new user you'll need the mySQL admin password.  You won't need unix root password unless you don't already have rights necessary to execute mySQL.  Once you're an accepted user of mySQL you can add database(s) without additional permission from the mySQL admin.

Possibly good news:

mySQL initially installs witout an admin/root password

HOWEVER:

For obvious reasons the first thing after installation MOST mySQL admins do is set a password.

Comment: Yeah, that might be helpful. I could try to do a local install and run off that. Thanks!